# FxCop Rule in SonarQube 4.5.7 on C# project

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, fxcop, sonarqube-4.5

I'm tring to run analysis on SonarQube, using an FxCop custom Rule.
In SonarQube 4.5.7 I add the rule to the set of rules, I activate it and then run the analysis.
To run the analysis I use the sequence of following commands:

```
1) MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:my.project.C-Sharp-ConsoleApp /n:C-Sharp-ConsoleApp /v:1.1
2) "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild" /T:Rebuild
3) MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

I see that the rule is executed, because when I run the second command I read the following part of log:

```
...
(RunCodeAnalysis target) ->
MSBUILD : warning CR1000: MyRules : Field 'CSharpSortNames.m_variabile' is not in Hungarian notation. Field name should be prefixed with 's'. [C:\Users\Alessandro\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\C-Sharp-ConsoleApp\C-Sharp-ConsoleApp\C-Sharp-ConsoleApp.csproj]
```

My custom rule checkID is CR1000, and after the third command, I see that an error of this rule is founded, but the web app doesn't let me see where. For all other errors the web app let me see the precise line where is the error by a link to the .cs file. For my rule it doesn't.
Anyone can help me about this?
Further problem is in SonarQube 5.4 the same rule is activated but web app does not show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause here is that FxCop uses information from the PDB file for providing location information. However, the PDB only contains information that would be useful for debugging scenarios, which means that FxCop rule violations that are associated with non-executable code (e.g.: field declarations or interface definitions) will not have location information available.  (FWIW, there is an open SonarQube [issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-446) for addressing this, but it would be non-trivial to accomplish unless SonarQube were to directly examine the source files to attempt to locate the field declaration.  I rather suspect they might not bother given that it simpler to address via a Roslyn analyzer.)

> Further problem is in SonarQube 5.4 the same rule is activated but web
>   app does not show the error.

That's because older versions of the [C# plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin) for SonarQube completely ignored FxCop violations without location information.  This was addressed in [version 5.2](https://jira.sonarsource.com/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10935&version=13051) of the plugin, which only became in early May 2016 (and is presumably what you used when you installed SonarQube 5.5).  It is compatible with version 5.4 of SonarQube, so you should be able to use it with your older installs if you like.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Next days I proof what you said, then I green mark your comment

Comment: On sonarqube 5.4 I had C# plugin 5.2, this didn't find errors about my FxCop custom rule.

Comment: On sonarqube 5.4 I had C# plugin 5.2, this didn't find errors about my FxCop custom rule. But if I update the C# plugin to v5.3 it find my custom rule. It is an error of declaration so it don't show the line code. So FxCop  violation without location information is addressed with C# plugin v5.3. Thanks. @NicoleCalinoiu